# extern inline function was referenced but not defined

Tags: c++, c, inline, extern

I have a function (lets call it `void foo(void) {}`) that I wish to be inline.But I defined it inside .cpp file.
I can not move the function to the header because it is using other functions from .cpp.

**EDIT:** 
code below just like real one is not using c++ features. I can clearly add:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
```

If i would like to convert code below to c99 i need only to change my project properties (or makefile if you like) **NOT THE CODE**. I am asking also about c++ because meaby it can solve my problem while c99 can not. 
**therefore C and C++ tags in my question are justified. the code is portable** 
 
see: [When to use extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292138/when-to-use-extern-c-in-c)

**EDIT #2** 
Ok i understand that i must put `foo()` definition inside header file. How can I call `func_a()` and `func_b()` from `foo()` without moving them to the header file? Is there any workaround?

Example 
**file.c / .cpp:**

```
int    func_a (int a,    int b,    int c)    {/*...*/};
double func_b (double a, double b, double c) {/*...*/};

void   foo    (int a, double b) { // unction definition
    //...
    int myInt = func_a(a, 2, 3);
    //...
    double myDouble = func_b(1.5f, b, 3.5f);
    //...
}
```

**file.h:**

```
// Something before.

void foo (int a, double b); // function declaration

// Something after.
```

**I want to point out:**

- I am working with Visual Studio 2015.
- I am writing relatively big project ( ~ 7000 Lines Of Code ). It is simulation of physical system.
- `file.h` is included to many other compilation units.
- `foo(int, double)` is small and it calls other functions from `file.cpp`
- I want to make `foo(int, double)` inline because of optimization reasons ( I will end up using `__forceinline__`)
- I am calling `foo()` many, many times across my program. Also it is used inside few while loops ( 100k + iterations each ) so it is expansive to let this symbol `foo()` be not inline.
- I am sick of header-only libraries.

**I tried to:** 
**file.c / .cpp:**

```
extern inline
void   foo    (int a, double b) {\*...*\}; // Definition
```

**file.h:**

```
extern inline
void   foo    (int a, double b); // Declaration
```

but I keep getting an warning:

```
warning : extern inline function "foo" was referenced but not defined
```

And i do not understand why i am getting this warning.

**Is there any way to:**

- keep definition of `foo()` inside my .cpp file ? But still make it inline
- move `foo()` to the `file.h`, keep `func_a()` and `func_b()` inside     `file.cpp`, but make `func_a()` and `func_b()` symbols "visible" to the `foo()` ( ! and only to the `foo()` ! ) from `file.cpp`
- any other workaround?

Sory I am still learning cpp and I dont know if my question is clear, or is it even possible to make function inline from .cpp file.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Don't add unrelated tags!

Comment: @olaf like you saw, i am not using c++ features. extern "C"  is something that i am using often in my code. `foo()` most probably will end up using it also. I was talking about c++ because meaby c++ can solve this problem while c can not

Comment: Please provide a reference to the C standard where this construct is specified. You also don't show this in your code. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The definition of an inline function must be present in the translation unit where it is accessed

Comment: why you don't want to put `func_a` `func_b` into header?

Comment: @appleapple Right now i am sick of header-only files. And i spend last 3 days just to rewrite my whole project from header-only to .h + .cpp / .c

Comment: isn't your current code doing it?

Comment: BTW, you can put `func_a` `func_b` into some (maybe nested) namespace so the current namespace will not have these two function.

Comment: sory, i have edited my comment. 
Thats the case, i have no idea. If it is doing it, why am i still getting warning : `warning : extern inline function "foo" was referenced but not defined`

Comment: i did not think about namespaces...

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29796264/1782465)

Comment: **[basic.def.odr]** says (paragraph 4) "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odd-used." You cannot use it in one translation unit but define it in another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, the `inline` keyword means this:

- The function's body *must* be present in every source file which uses that function.
- The function's "bodies" in all source files must be token-by-token and entity-by-entity identical.
- The compiler&linker must make sure they're fine with the function having these "multiple bodies"

That's all that it does. In practice, this means that it enables *and forces* you to put the function body into a header file.

The keyword itself has nothing to do with function inlining, per se. It's just that if the *compiler* wants to be able to inline the function's body, it must have access to it when compiling the calling code; in other words, the function's body must be in the same source file or in a header file included by that source file.

If you want to enable the *compiler* to inline the function in all call sites, and these call sites happen in more than one source file, you have to put the function into a header file (and mark it as `inline`).

On the other hand, it is also possible for the *linker* to do inlining, called Link-Time Code Generation or Whole Program Optimisation or something similar (depending on your toolchain's vendor). Enabling this will

1. extend your build times, and
2. allow the linker to inline functions into call sites *across source files*

So to inline the function, you have two options. Either put the function into a header file, or enable and rely on link-time optimisation to inline it for you.

---

In your particular case, to use `__forceinline__`, you'll have define `foo` in a header file. This requires the definition of `foo` to see declarations of `func_a` and `func_b`. To prevent namespace polution, you can declare these functions within the scope of `foo`:

```
inline void foo(int a, double b) { // function definition
    int func_a(int, int, int);
    double func_b(double, double, double);

    //...
    int myInt = func_a(a, 2, 3);
    //...
    double myDouble = func_b(1.5f, b, 3.5f);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping that i could leave my function definition inside src file. Therefore is there any way to make `func_a()` and `func_b()` visible to the `foo()` from src file ? 
BTW this code will end up with `__forceinline__` not `inline` key-word soo i will be able to force my compiler to inline it everywhere.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 Can you simply declare (not define) the functions in the header file?

Comment: I will end up then with header-only library. And i dont like it. Also i will declare many symbols, that i will not use therefor they should not be visible outside of `file.cpp`, I am thinking here about code - encapsulation.