# Why are there inline function declarations instead of inline function calls?

Tags: c++

C++ (and various other languages) support inline functions. If I want a function to be inlined, I have to use the `inline` keyword in the declaration. To me, this seams pretty unintuitive: Why can't I just use `inline` when calling a function? Example:

```
void foo(){...}
inline foo();
```

instead of

```
inline void foo(...){...}
foo();
```

This would allow me to inline the function in only specific places without having to duplicate the function. Also, every function could be inlined, which would make the mechanism much more flexible. Is there a reason for why this is not support?

Comment: _If I want a function to be inlined_ that is worng. The compiler decides when which function is inlined.

Comment: You can can get that functionality if you really want to already.

`inline void ilfoo() {...}  void foo() {ilfoo();}`

Comment: The inline keyword is pretty much defunct the compiler is the ultimate judge now

Comment: @JakeFreeman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method  has an example of where inline isn't defunct - ie "function is defined in multiple units".

Comment: @JakeFreeman The `inline` keyword still works perfectly well, only its role has now changed and it no longer suggests inlining.

Comment: [Related reading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29796264/1782465)

Comment: (why is often a hard question.)

Comment: See also [C++ Super FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#where-to-put-inline-keyword)

Comment: @Angew @JakeFreeman Wrong. GCC will happily listen to `inline` advise and will inline functions it would not inline otherwise. At least when building in C mode. I _does_ make a difference.

Comment: @Ivan C is not C++.

Comment: @manni66 The question includes "various other languages". Which basically means C too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Foreword:

To *inline a function* i.e. the act of *inlining* i.e. *inline expansion* is an optimization where a function call is replaced by duplicated set of instructions.

To declare an *inline function* is to declare to the linker that the function is to be treated differently than non-inline functions. Specifically, the one-definition-rule is different for inline functions. Inline functions are allowed to be defined in multiple translation units (and in fact required to be defined in all translation units where the function is odr-used). This is different from non-inline functions, which must be defined in exactly one translation unit. The `inline` keyword can be used the declare an inline function.

While inline declaration is named similarly to the inlining optimization, and while former can indirectly affect whether latter is possible, these two concepts are separate.

Now, to the answer.

---

> If I want a function to be inlined, I have to use the `inline` keyword in the declaration.

You don't necessarily have to use the inline keyword. A call to a non-inline function can be expanded inline by the compiler if the function is defined in the same translation unit. Even that is not a requirement for a linktime optimizer which sees all translation units.

Example:

```
// a.cpp
void foo(){}        // a non-inline function
inline void qux(){} // an inline function
void bar(){
    foo(); // this call to a non-inline function can be expanded inline
           // because the function is defined in the same TU
}

// b.cpp
void foo(); // the non-inline function must not be defined
            // in multiple translation units
inline void qux(){} // the inline function can and must be defined
                    // in both translation units
void xeb(){
    foo(); // this call to a non-inline function can not be expanded inline by
           // the compiler because the function is not defined in the same TU
           // the call can be expanded by a linker
    qux(); // this call can be expanded by the compiler
           // because the function is defined in the same TU
}
```

That said, linktime optimization isn't always an option, and function calls do happen across translation units, so inline definition is in some cases indeed necessary to allow inline expansion.

A pedantic point: A function can declared inline without the `inline` keyword (if it is a member function).

> Why can't I just use inline when calling a function?

There just isn't such syntax in the language.

Note that the function would still have to be defined in the same translation unit or else it cannot be expanded inline by the compiler. Thus the function would still need to be declared inline if you wanted inline expansion in more than one translation unit.

I suspect that the reason why there is no syntax to force inline expansion is probably the same as why there is no way to select which branch of an `if` statement is the "default" branch which might have marginal effect on performance (the reasoning is just my guess in both cases): Humans are notoriously bad at optimization. I see no technical reason why such language feature couldn't be introduced. But I wouldn't expect such feature to be very useful.

Comment: _A call to a non-inline function can be **expanded** inline by the compiler if the function is **defined** in the same translation unit._ my point: is that true even when the function has/gets multiple calls (because you said it is non-inline)

Comment: @MohammadKanan yes. Multipe calls can be expanded inline.

Comment: 10x, I just read they will be shared across all translation units (static objects & variables)

Comment: @MohammadKanan I added clarifying foreword. Perhaps it will be of use to you.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ `inline` *does not* mean that the calls should get inlined. It means that the definition is allowed to occur in multiple translation units, whereas normally only one definition is allowed.

Since header files are usually included in many translation units of the C++ program, any function definition in a header file will end up in multiple translation units. So, to make that work, you need the `inline` keyword for those definitions. It's still related to inlining though, since in this case (where the definition is in the header), the definition is available at all call sites that include the header, allowing the compiler to inline it, since it knows the full definition. If only a declaration would be available in the header, inlining would only be possible during linking (with 'link time optimization' aka LTO).

Comment: what do you mean by: does not mean that the **_calls should get inlined_**

Comment: It means this keyword is not about substituting a function's body into the locating where the function is called.

Comment: @TheTechel, but by definition its a suggestion to do that  .. while the rest explains its properties , from point 2 in description http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @Mohammad - The current definition of inline does not say it is a suggestion. It only says what M-ou-se and I say it says. The standards committee simply did not want to introduce a new keyword, so instead they used "inline" which no longer meant anything at all.

Comment: @JiveDadson, in case you missed my point, its a _suggestion_ to the compiler .. Its not my _word_ .. read it in the first note here: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/

Comment: @Mohammad - cplusplus.com has too many errors, and that's one of them. Prefer cppreference.com. This gets it right: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline "The original intent of the inline keyword was ..."

Comment: @JiveDadson, Yes that was my reference source in answer to TheTechel

Comment: @Mohammad - But it is no longer a suggestion. You're not going all backfire effect I hope. :-) Have the last word....

Comment: @JiveDadson, :)  for the most part the doc intro emphasizes  _implicitly_  in-lined funcs .. so no more suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

Short but sweet answer: "Inline" does not do what it used to. These days, all it means is that the linker should ignore multiple definitions from separate compilation units, and just pick one and go with it. The compiler is free to do as it pleases. Most or all modern compilers ignore "inline".

Bonus fact: In the latest and greatest C++, you can declare a variable as inline.

Comment: There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

Comment: @MohammadKanan - I think that's what I said,

Comment: _the linker should **ignore** multiple definitions from separate compilation units._ and just  pick one .. this appeared as if you mean those others won't be inlined

Comment: @Mohammad Appearances can be deceiving. :-) The linker does not know whether the compiler rolled a function out in-line in a given compilation unit or just never saw it.