# Template Specialization and Library Optimization in C++

Tags: c++

I've been revisiting template specialization in C++, and a friend raised an interesting question that I couldn't answer satisfactorily. The question is, if template specialization can be used to include only necessary code in the final output program file, why isn't it commonly used for libraries?

In a scenario where a function isn't used, it could be excluded from the output object file, potentially reducing the final executable size. Unlike when using non-template functions from a library, where even unused functions find a place in the output file.

My initial thought was that it might impact compile time, but are there other reasons? If someone prioritizes output file size over compile time and doesn't mind longer compile times, could template specialization be a valid solution? I'm aware of compile time optimizations, but is template specialization a viable option for those looking to minimize output file size?

To expand on what I am asking, here is the `main.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
}

template <int n>
void bar() {
    std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    foo();

    bar<0>();

    return 0;
}
```

use the below command to get the assembly file

`g++ main.cpp -o main.asm -S -masm=intel -O3`

We notice the presence of `foo` and `bar` functions in the code.

Now, delete the calls to `foo()` and `bar<0>()` from the `main()` function and recompile using the provided command.

In the resulting assembly file, there won't be any reference to `bar()` since it wasn't used, but `foo()` will still be mentioned.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this. Specialization is rarely used because there's rarely a need for it. Also I believe it is beneficial for code maintenance to not specialize templates and keep them generic.

Comment: *"why isn't it commonly used for libraries?"* -- Are you intentionally excluding two very common libraries (standard library and Boost, which make heavy use of templates)?

Comment: *"even unused functions find a place in the output file"* -- this is neither mandated by the standard nor true of all tool chains. Linkers are allowed to -- and some do -- remove unused functions from the output file.

Comment: @JaMiT Certainly, I recognize their usage, but it's important to note that their utilization of templates isn't exclusively aimed at minimizing the file output size. While it might seem like a small or unconventional question, contemplating templates from this perspective is not incorrect. I'm simply inquiring: what drawbacks, if any, exist in this approach? Are there any adverse effects to consider? I know the question might even sound silly, but thanks for giving your time to answer :)

Comment: @JaMiT Your second comment might be a valid reason that I hadn't considered. I'll hold off and see if anyone else has a different explanation.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking why we don't make `foo` a template too so that it will be eliminated from the generated code if unused?

Comment: Providing an example is good, but it might be suffering from some form of [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) since you chose it to demonstrate a specific case. Would it be more fair to add another use of `bar` in your code, as in `int main() { foo(); bar<0>(); bar<1>(); return 0; }`?

Comment: You could make `foo` `inline` (or move it in unnamed namespace). It may non longer be in .obj neither.

Comment: Jarod42 brings up a good point. To remove distractions from your comparison, you should remove as many differences as possible, leaving only the "template vs. non-template" difference. One difference in the current example is that the definition of `bar` *must* occur in a header file, while the definition of `foo` *cannot* occur in a header file. Changing the definition to `inline void foo() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }` would remove this difference. How does this affect your experiment's result?

Comment: @JaMiT, yeah, indeed. Making those changes removed references to foo() as well when not used in main(). Then one could even use inline for the very same reasons that I mentioned earlier. Given that inline is just a request and can be ignored by the compiler, it won't have as much effect on compile time as the use of templates. Thanks a lot for clearing up my doubt :)

Comment: @vikram *"Given that inline is just a request and can be ignored by the compiler"* -- The keyword `inline` is not "just a request". It instructs the compiler and linker to expect that the full function definition will appear in every translation unit where the function is used. Hard requirement. *(You might be thinking of inlining function calls, but that is not part of the meaning of the `inline` keyword, as far as the language standard is concerned.)*

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, I was thinking of inlining function calls. I read other answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796264/is-there-still-a-use-for-inline) and understand it now. Thanks :)